# Sklearn Error: "AttributeError: 'MissingValues' object has no attribute 'to_list'"

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I'm making my first steps in ML, and following a code given to me in an online course:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')

#Encoding categorial data:
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder',OneHotEncoder(),[0])], remainder='passthrough')
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X))
print(X)
```

The last block in the code should take a column containing country names ('Germany','France','Italy') and encode them with OneHotEncoder.
In the course video, everything works out fine, but when I try to run it in Pycharm, the following error comes up, regarding the last line in the code:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/Users/XXXX/Desktop/main.py", line 22, in 
> X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X))
>
> ...
>
> "AttributeError: 'MissingValues' object has no attribute 'to_list'"

Anyone ever came accross this error?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define X. From what I see, your problem is not defining the variables correctly. Try fitting the column transformer to the dataset, not X. (ct.fit_transform(dataset))